# How do I reapair this clear plastic coating peeling from my cabient door?

Tags: doors, kitchens, cupboard

Protective coatings are thin and easily removed, this issue is the peeling of a much thicker plastic that provides a glossy sheen finish.

Could a certain adhesive be used to stick it down? I'm loath to remove it and attempt to cover the whole freezer door with some other vinyl type coating.

(I spotted a small piece of some original protective film on the bottom edge of the door that had been accidentally left on, and photographed that too, so I know the issue I'm trying to fix is not one of protective film).

[image: Peeling-film]

Comment: I'd go with you spotted a pice of old shrink-wrap palletizing film elsewhere on top of this, and this is the protective plastic to keep the door paint nice until installed, but you probably won't believe me.

Comment: @Ecnerwal is right… protective plastic on the edging has no reason to be exactly the same thickness as that on the panel.

Comment: Agree with the 2 comments above. That is not a film to add gloss, it is protective and meant to be removed after installation.

Answer (score 3):

What are you seeing is a protective film.

I work in a cabinet shop. The door is  made of a white melamine or plastic laminate and edge banding which covers the cut edges. The door has been covered in a protective film.

This film can be removed.  During transport we typically wrap our cabinets, doors and shelving packs to protect them and then remove once delivered and the installation process has begun.

I do not know of any films like this that are meant to be permanent and left in place.

Comment: First and foremost, thanks for everyone’s thoughts. 

The kitchen was installed before we bought the house and so I don’t really have any recourse to refer to the supplier. 

However what I did notice on the thin protective film on the lower edge of this panel I photographed was some very clear instruction that that part was indeed protective and had to be removed immediately after installation. I would have thought that the same would be on the now peeling part too, no?  This film is not easy to remove at all

Comment: Not all films are the same. The thicker stuff could've been from the shrink wrapping. We shrink wrap bundles of adjustable shelves and other materials.  If you're having trouble removing the film please create a new question and we can help get you going in the right direction.

Comment: If this answered your question please consider hitting the check mark to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The peeling clear plastic is indeed part of the glossy finish and needs to be glued back down.

I managed to get hold of the previous owner who installed the kitchen in 2011, and he confirmed that the protective film was bluish and had already been removed.

I’ve now glued down the peeling layer with super glue gel, though there might have been a better adhesive out there, applying a thin bead across the area. It’s not perfect but will do.

Once again, thanks for everyone’s thoughts.

Comment: That is a _VERY_ odd situation. Your panel is definitely a melamine or other laminate, but it does look like there's an _extra_ layer of clear gloss plastic over the top of it that definitely looks like a protective coating. However, your confirmation with the previous owner does discount that. Usually, one would use contact cement to adhere a laminate, but that would definitely show through this clear coat, so superglue might have been your best choice. I'd imagine that this was originally heat sealed onto the doors.

Comment: Since you've got contact info for the previous owner and he seems helpful, you may want to get in touch one more time to find out who made these cabinets so you can go directly to them if any issues arise in the future. It might be worth finding out about how your specific cabinets were made and if they have any sort of lifetime/transferable warranty and/or repair recommendations.